# SVN: How to update only the files that were modifed in the revision

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it possible to update only the files that were affected by the last commit? In one command preferably, on linux.

EDIT:

Example.
First i commit files 1 and 2. Then i commit files 3 and 4. Now i want to update only files 3 and 4 without updating 1 and 2.

Comment: What do you mean update - you mean merge in only a single revision's worth of changes to a working copy that isn't up-to-date? Or avoid updating timestamps of other files (I don't think that happens anyway). BTW the svn command line syntax is identical on Windows and Linux (AFAICR - maybe some corner cases).

Comment: "merge in only a single revision's worth of changes to a working copy that isn't up-to-date" - that. I mentioned linux because someone might suggest a one liner that uses linux in some way.

Answer (score 12):

If you like to update particular files you have to give them on command line:

```
svn update file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you wan't it more handy you can write a script to do this..

Update:In the example what you described in your question: you don't need to update the files, cause they are already update based on the commit you did before. So i think you are thinking of a different working copy.

Comment: but is it possible to achieve the same thing without typing in file names manually?

Comment: what kind of script would that be?

Comment: You can use the output of svn log -l 1 ^/trunk to get the information you need. The other question is: What are you trying to achieve, cause based on the example you gave the files in your working copy will not be updated, cause they are already up-to-date based on your commit.

Comment: i'm trying to update a different working copy. Thanks for the tip about ^/trunk

Comment: But under which circumstances wouldn't you update the second working copy. You can use the revision number for the second working copy. Like svn update -r Rev1 and the next step svn update -r Rev2 etc.

Comment: well there might be conflicts in the files from other commits and i don't want to be resolving those conflicts myself.

Comment: The working copy you would like to update does this contain manual changes? If yes this could happen otherwise it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your working copy with only selected commits, you have to merge them in - you're effectively creating a local branch with cherry-picked commits from trunk, although the final update should pick them up OK. You'll want

```
svn log -l 1 http://remote-repository-url/
```

to find the revision number you want, then

```
svn merge -c 12345 http://remote-repository-url/
```

to merge future commit 12345 into your WC.

Or, if changes are committed in disjoint directories, you can simply

```
svn update dir-with-changes
```

to split the revision of your WC and pick up only changes in the named directory.

Comment: about svn update dir-with-changes; what if there are files in this directory which i don't want to update and files which i want to update